# Parsing HTML Table - PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to parse many HTML tables, with the URLs stored in the database. The current problem with my code is that it will fail on a different table every time. Here is the part of the code that gets the error:

```
while ($sqlrow = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
echo "Started Processing Table " . $tables . PHP_EOL;
$tables++;
$data = file_get_contents($sqlrow[1]);
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$teamtable               = $dom->getElementById("reTeamTable");
$teamrows                = $teamtable->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

The lines that usually fails is either the "getElementById" command or the "getElementsByTagName" command. The error I am getting is: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /scouting/teamlist.php on line 20". I don't understand why this is getting an error on a different URL every time.

Comment: have you declared `$dom`?

Comment: Yes I have declared $dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its means that $dom doesnt find element with `id="reTeamTable"` ( `$teamtable` is null ). Before call   `getElementsByTagName` , check `$teamtable` on empty.